# Keep a control on top in the delphi designer

Tags: delphi, designer

I created a simple design-time component that helps to select and bring to front other components on the same form. (It is more convenient than IDE object tree view when designing full screen forms in a single monitor environment). But in Delphi XE2, I cannot reliably ensure and detect that the helper component itself is on the top. When I select it, the IDE draws 8 blue balls as a marker around it, and it seems to me that those markers are part of the actual top level window.

So, how could I check if a component is selected in the IDE designer?

Comment: You do know that you can 'unpin' the `Structure View` and call it up with `Shift` - `Alt` - `F11`?

Answer (score 0):

> So, how could I check if a component is selected in the IDE designer?

Create a design-time editor for your component (make sure you implement it in a designtime-only package, not a runtime package), and register it with `RegisterComponentEditor()`.  `TComponentEditor` has a `Designer` property to access the Form Designer's `IDesigner` interface, which has a `GetSelections()` method:

```
procedure GetSelections(const List: IDesignerSelections);
```

`IDesignerSelections` has `Count` and `Items[]` properties, where `Items[]` returns a `TPersistent` object.  So you can loop through the list looking for your desired component object(s) (all components derive from `TPersistent`).

`IDesigner` also has `SelectComponent()` and `SetSelections()` methods, so you can have the Form Designer select other components as needed:

```
procedure SelectComponent(Instance: TPersistent); overload;
procedure SelectComponent(const ADesignObject: IDesignObject); overload;
procedure SetSelections(const List: IDesignerSelections);
```

Comment: Sorry, I was unable to format it as 'code'. Please someone delete it.

Comment: @malom: you should be able to delete it yourself.